# Detect quoted strings with fscanf

Tags: c, regex, strcmp

I want to read in C the content of a file like this:

```
foo="bar"
alice="bob"
fruit="pineapple"
```

And I am interested in the specific value associated with the key *alice*, but without the surrounding quotes. So, I want ***bob***.

So, I've written something like this

**EDIT: Added printf of key/value**

```
char key[20];
char value[20];
char output[20];

memset(key, 0, 20);
memset(value, 0, 20);

while(fscanf(fd, "%19[^=]=\"%19[^\"]\"", key, value) != EOF) {

    printf("%s=%s", key, value);

    if (strcmp(key, "alice") == 0) {
      memset(output, 0, 20);
      strncpy(output, value, 20);
      break;
    }

    memset(key, 0, 20);
    memset(value, 0, 20);
}
```

The problem is the strcmp never returns 0. So, the comparation between any key and "alice" is always false. And I'm getting this output:

```
foo=bar
alice=bob
fruit=pinneaple
=pineapple
```

Also tested the length of each key, by strlen, and it's correct. Apart from the last line of rubish, I get what I expect. So, I don't really understand...

Is there any obvious error here? I'm trying to debug the code, but I'm working with a target system very limited (openwrt), and I don't have access to gdb (actually, the code is cross-compiled in another machine, because my target one doesn't even have a compiler).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This might help you. [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/wR5cQ3/12)

Comment: You might print out the variable `key` and `value`, to see what they really are. Or use a debugger and step through line by line and check the contents of those variables.

Comment: Thanks. It's something similar to http://www.regexr.com/. But I'm not sure about the differences between classic regexp and scanf syntax. I'm doing something wrong for sure.

Comment: @Braj The [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) matching is not regular expressions. Ther is one single format code that is *similar* to a regular expression, but it's not.

Comment: You might want to see e.g. [this example of your code](http://ideone.com/6iWKgi). It explains quite a lot. Compare to e.g. [this one](http://ideone.com/lTMn8Y).

Comment: Wow, @JoachimPileborg, that worked! So, the last \n of each line was considered as the first character of the next one. And the starting whitespace in the format string makes fscanf ignore it. Right? Many thanks for all your comments!

Comment: `[]` don't have the whitespace skipping effect that the other format codes have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `scanf()` for user input (even when it comes from a file).
Prefer `fgets()`.

Your immediate problem is with whitespace.

The contents of the file include `'\n'`. The `'\n'` are included in `key`.

If you want to keep using `fscanf()` try adding some spaces inside the conversion string:

```
while (fscanf(fd, " %19[^=]= \"%19[^\"]\"", key, value) == 2) /* ... */;
//                 ^        ^ (2nd one isn't as important)
```

Also notice I changed the condition.
Rather than testing against `EOF`, test for a return value of `2`.